# algebraic structure as set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does anyone know how to do this problem? What do I have to look at to find out what kind of a algebraic stucture is this. I have done similar ones but not with functions so im struggling a bit

What kind of algebraic structure is set

$\{
f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}|~
f~ \text{is bijection},
f(n)\neq n
~\text{only for a finite number of natural numbers n }\}$

in point of multiplication of conversions (taking a compound function)

Comment: When you only have one operation, there are not so many algebraic structures to consider. Try to verify the group axioms.

Comment: Also notice that you "expect" something like a group, because this is a structure that "wants to be" the union of all the $S_n$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.